# Line breaks in a PHP contact form

Tags: php, html

I need to add a contact form to a website I'm making, and found a useful bit of code someone had kindly shared for the likes of me who have no PHP experience.

After pasting and editing the code into the page and uploading it to a staging site, I tested it using my gmail address and it works fine. The only thing is that the email text has no line breaks in it.

**Here's the code:**

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
$ToEmail = 'myemailadress@gmail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
Your message was sent
<?php 
} else { 
?>
<form action="contactus.php" method="post">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="29%" class="bodytext">Your name:</td>
<td width="71%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext">Email address:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext">Comment:</td>
<td><textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" id="comment" class="bodytext"> </textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext"> </td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form> 
<?php 
}; 
?>
```

**This is what I receive when it arrives in my inbox:**

> Name: Mr J BloggsEmail: email@address.comComment: Comments text.

**What I'd like is for it to instead look like this:**

> Name: Mr J Bloggs
>   Email: email@address.com
>   Comment: Comments text.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add line break after each row:

```
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br/>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br/>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this just added a space instead of a break, same went for adding \r\n to the ends of the code. In hindsight the "MESSAGE_BODY" parts should have tipped me off to where I needed to be looking.

Comment: @number8pie if the mail is html you should add `<br />`, your mail looke like plain text to me

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up if, I ever get emails with the <br /> tag in them I'll use the \n method instead.